# set Highstock xAxis range within options object

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

My React components pulls data for an API. The `options.series.data` data for the yAxis is what receives the API data.

The component is enabled to pull the data range for day/hour/minute which comes with a datestamp for when the data was recorded. How do I dynamically set the xAxis min/max range to respect the day/hour/minute duration change?

The HighchartsReact instance receives the data series via the `options` object that's where I'd like to setup the dynamic xAxis handler method. Perhaps it's `setExtemes()`.

The component code is below.

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import highchartsStockChart from 'highcharts/modules/stock';
import { getDaily, getHourly, getMinute } from '../actions/getData';
import Spinner from './Spinner';

Highcharts.setOptions({
  lang: {
    thousandsSep: ','
  }
});
highchartsStockChart(Highcharts);

const Chart = ({
  match,
  list: { list, loading },
  getDaily,
  getHourly,
  getMinute,
  error
}) => {
  const [method, setMethod] = useState(() => getDaily);

  useEffect(() => {
    method(match.params.currency.toUpperCase(), 30);
  }, [match.params.currency, method]);

  console.log('Chart.js list:', list);
  console.log('Chart.js error:', error);
  console.log('Chart.js loading:', loading);

  const options = {
    title: {
      text: 'Close Price'
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'close price',
      data: list.map(item => item.close),
      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'close price: ${point.y:,.2f}'
      },
      animation: false
    }],
    scrollbar: {
      enabled: false
    },
    navigator: {
      enabled: false
    },
    rangeSelector: {
      inputEnabled: false,
      allButtonsEnabled: true,
      buttonSpacing: 10,
      buttonPosition: {
        align: 'left'
      },
      buttons: [{
        type: 'day',
        count: 1,
        text: 'Day',
        events: {
          click: () => setMethod(() => getDaily)
        }
      }, {
        type: 'hour',
        count: 1,
        text: 'Hour',
        events: {
          click: () => setMethod(() => getHourly)
        }
      }, {
        type: 'minute',
        count: 1,
        text: 'Minute',
        events: {
          click: () => setMethod(() => getMinute)
        }
      }]
    }
  };

  let content;
  if (error && error.message) {
    content = error.message;
  } else if (!list.length || loading) {
    content = <Spinner />;
  } else {
    content = (
      <Fragment>
        {list.map(item => <span key={item.time}>{item.close} </span>)}
        <button onClick={() => setMethod(() => getHourly)}>set Hourly</button>
        <button onClick={() => setMethod(() => getMinute)}>set Minute</button>
        <HighchartsReact
          highcharts={Highcharts}
          options={options}
          constructorType={'stockChart'}
        />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      Chart.
      {content}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  list: state.data,
  error: state.error
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getDaily, getHourly, getMinute })(Chart);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- use chart `redraw` event callback function and call `setExtremes`:

---

```
chart: {
    events: {
        redraw: function() {
            if (allowChartRedraw) {
                allowChartRedraw = false;
                this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(0, Math.random() * 3);
            }

            allowChartRedraw = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wvpnct9h/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.redraw

---

- keep all of the options in a state and manipulate axis extremes by `min` and `max` properties:

---

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    chartOptions: {
      series: [
        {
          data: [Math.random() * 3, Math.random() * 3, Math.random() * 3]
        }
      ],
      xAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: Math.random() * 3
      }
    }
  });
}
```

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-jo6nw

---

- get the chart reference and call `setExtremes` on the `xAxis`.

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#how-to-get-a-chart-instance

Comment: Tried the 3rd way but since the `ref` to the `Highcharts` instance is defined with `const chartRef = useRef(null)` before `render()` after the charts's rendered `chartRef` is set back to `null`. Here's my current code: https://pastebin.com/dpQQqCEu

Comment: Hi @El Anonimo, Please try to store the chart reference in a callback function, like in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you that worked. I wonder how do they get a reference for the `chart` argument they feed to the `afterChartCreated(chart)` call.

Comment: El Anonimo - component is binded as `this` and `chart` is passed as a function argument.

Comment: Would provide a code snippet please? What could the binding look like?

Comment: Sure, please check this one: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-nf35z